# jQuery Validation with Telerik tabstrip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, telerik

I am creating a multi-step form using telerik tabstrip.
I have 3 tabs and each page view is a different user controls.
and i want to validated few controls in each tab.

PFB the code tabstrip

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpannel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="demo-container">
            <div class="wizardHeader"></div>
            <div style="float: left">
                <telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RequestRadTabStrip" Orientation="VerticalLeft" MultiPageID="ReqRadMultiPage" SelectedIndex="0" CausesValidation="false">
                    <Tabs>
                        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Step1" Width="200px" Selected="true" PageViewID="page1"></telerik:RadTab>
                        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Step2" Width="200px" PageViewID="page2"></telerik:RadTab>
                        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Step3" Width="200px" PageViewID="page3"></telerik:RadTab>
                    </Tabs>
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
            </div>
            <div ">
                <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="ReqRadMultiPage" SelectedIndex="0" OnInit="ReqRadMultiPage_Init">
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="page1" ValidationGroup="ReqGI">
                         <usExp:step1 runat="server" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="page2">
                         <usExp:step2 runat="server" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="page3">
                         <usExp:step3 runat="server" />
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                </telerik:RadMultiPage>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_button">
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" ID="btnCont" Text="Continue" OnClick="btnCont_Click" OnClientClick="OnClientClicked()" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="ReqGI" />
            </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On Continue button click i am calling jQuery function for moving from 1 tab to other.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnClientClicked() {
        var radtabstrip = $find("<%=RequestRadTabStrip.ClientID %>");
        var count = radtabstrip.get_tabs().get_count();
        var currentindex = radtabstrip.get_selectedIndex();
        var nextindex = currentindex + 1;
        if (nextindex < count) {
            radtabstrip.set_selectedIndex(nextindex);
        }
    }



</script>
```

Now on this "Continue" button click i want to do validation before switching it to next tab.
Could anyone help me out here?
Note: the fields to be validated are in user controls.
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What are you struggling with?Just access the data inside the controls by ID using jQuery and compare it to a list of expected values and types and if everything passes go to the next page.What's the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a Wizard control?  Moving through steps in order seems like that kind of flow.  RadTabStrip lets you click on any tab at any time.

Comment: Also, look into the Page_ClientValidate(validationGroupName) method that comes with WebForms so you can easily trigger your validators.